# How to show TODO FIXME inside a block in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, todo

The title explains itself.

Here is the sample code:

```
[stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:stillImageConnection
    completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {

        // TODO: bla bla bla
    }
 ];
```

TODO will not show in the method list in xcode.

But if I move the TODO upon to the method(that means: outside the block), it will be shown normally.

```
// TODO: bla bla bla
[stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:stillImageConnection
    completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {

        // some codes
    }
 ];
```

Any tips or workaround?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
#warning TODO: fix later...
```

to get a compile warning or

```
#error FIXME: fix now!
```

to get a compile error

You can also use a build script to mark them as warnings:

```
KEYWORDS="TODO|FIXME|\?\?\?:|\!\!\!:"
find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" \) -print0 | \
xargs -0 egrep --with-filename --line-number --only-matching "($KEYWORDS).*\$" | \
perl -p -e "s/($KEYWORDS)/ warning: \$1/"
```

Credit: http://www.benzado.com/blog/post/329/make-xcode-nag-you-about-unfinished-todos